# Inconsistent use of scroll bars across browsers (from inconsistent font rendering?)

Tags: bug, user-interface

After editing an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18110543/85661) to shorten long lines to remove large horizontal scroll bars I noticed that the largest codeblock had about 2 pixels of vertical scroll in Firefox which looked really sloppy.  I then compared across the other browsers on my system. Chrome didn't have a vertical scrollbar but put a horizontal one of a few pixels on the 2nd code block.  Edge and IE have scroll both of the scroll bars.

I can't easily tell what's going on vertically, but in the 2nd code block FF is rendering the text slightly narrower than the other browsers are.

Is this a case of browsers still not quite rendering html identically, or is SO's layout glitching somehow?

If OS also turns out to matter, I'm running win10 v1511.

Screenshot from edge showing scrollbars in both places (Chrome doesn't show the top one, FireFox doesn't show the bottom one).
[image: https://i.imgur.com/sN1Vaaq.png]

Comment: "Is this a case of browsers still not quite rendering html identically" browsers (and OSs) will never render anything identically and it's probably more than "quite" :) (not sure if there's anything else going on here though btw, not at a computer to look)

Comment: @Cai In most cases today on a given platform the results are functionally identical. We've came a long way since the late 90s when Netscape and Internet Explorer were different enough that some sites would offer users two different versions of the same content to work around major rendering differences.  IMO if it's a browser/os font rendering issue the horizontal scroll bar might not be something that SO can do anything about (if the text does not fit, you must acquit), but the logic behind showing all the code or a vertical scrollbar shouldn't produce obviously bad results like this anywhere

Comment: Of course the differences are minuscule compared to 15 years ago but I'd wouldn't say identical (I've just spent an entire day today working out infuriating browser inconsistencies), especially things like scroll bars which are mostly handled exclusively by browser/OS rather than CSS